# What affects would magic potions have on medicine and trade?

Tags: magic, medicine

I got a world in which magic potions cure all non magical diseases with ease.

They are used for humans, animals, and even added to water that would be used to grow plants and crops and so on.

Potions are, for obvious reasons, very widespread with even the most basic town or village having access to it.
This is mostly because the ruling body of magic is regulating the things. That is they make sure that they are authentic and they are readily available to people and that no merchant or vendors abuses the thing.
This led to them being affordable very popular.

Points on the potions for a clearer picture. And I hope they are enough.

- The stronger the potion the better the effect.
- They can close wounds and mend broken bones.
- Most are made to target a particular thing to make it easier.
- Like there is a cough medicine, but if it did not help then a stronger potion is used.
- Stamina and general fitness potions exist.
- They simply cure whatever the diseases, from cancer to the common cold.
- They can only heal diseases but not birth defects and other similar things.
- Yes. Magical cosmetic surgeons exist, but not very respected.
- People still clean wounds and close them. But no herbal remedies and doctors are just people who use the appropriate potion or wizards.
- Potions are made by wizards. No one else can make them or even attempt so. Researchers who try are often found dead. And it is, so far, simply impossible to do so without a wizard.
- In certain extreme cases only a wizard can heal the person. Like if a person lost an arm, no potion can heal them. But a wizard can then start healing them, helping them grow the thing back.
- The ruling body of wizard regulates the selling and making of thing. Licenses are given to people and the punishment for unauthorized potions is death. They are also wizards. They actually enforce the laws.
- Rulers, kings, state heads...etc are ok with the thing. They are given the best of potions and the increased health and crops yield is better for them.
- Certain potions are known to have be very addictive. But that just means you simply couple the desired feeling potion with another curing element and you are good to go.

Now the questions.

1. What would that mean to medicine? It's pre-industrial revolutions society anyway.
2. Would doctors or medical researchers even exist or continue to be a thing?
   I already have small groups that do it to spit the wizards but I'm talking about most people.
3. How would farmers use thing realistically? besides my method of just pouring the thing into the water or giving it to the animal.
4. What would that mean for trade? Besides the fact that a whole class of people exist around growing and gathering ingredient for wizards? Like am I missing something here?
5. If there are places in the world with little access to potions. Would they try to have more of them or just continue with pre modern medicine practices?
6. Any interesting points arising form the above situation?

Comment: One question only, please.  Also, the key constraint are the economics - what are potion prices (as constrained by the wizard guild)?  If it costs 2 sheep to heal one sick sheep then they will not be used on livestock.  If it costs 10 years of wages to fix a broken bone then only nobles will get broken bone potions.

Comment: Most of my questions come back to 1 central point.
Like I said they are common.
I still have not figured out the whole economy yet.
But again they are cheap enough so that even a simple peasant can afford one if he needs it.
Because it's such a huge trade and also because wizards found it beneficial for them to reduce the prices and increase the availability.

Comment: Why would it be beneficial for the wizards to reduce prices? Are the resources and labour on their end so cheap?

Comment: @Seallussus Pharmaceutical companies and healthcare costs in places with no healthcare provided by the state would tell you that your fantasy concept is only suitable for kindergarten literature.

Comment: @Rekesoft That's a bit harsh, but at the very least it's not how it would work in the real world. Then again we're dealing with a world where magic potions exist to cure and fix all needs.

Comment: @Seallussus, though I know all of your doubts come from one single factor, please divide them in more than one question. As it is, though 1 and 2 can be fused into one, you still have at least 5 questions in 1, most of them differently related to completely different themes, from medicine to economy to potential uses in farms to whether cultures would adopt them (which is honestly up to you, but yes, I do think they'd rather use what they've already been using, safe for really good potions). Please define what you want solved first and ask other questions regarding the other problems.

Comment: @basklein I didn't mean it to be harsh, but you're right, the sentence looks derogatory. It was not intended as such. I love literature for children. I only pointed (as other comments had already said) that if the story is not targeted to children the economy of this world must be careful thought.

Comment: @basklein,
Indeed. It's very easy to make them and costs little magical power.
Furthermore the amount of ability and skill for a wizard to make them is much lower than those who can move mountains.
It's also a political thing.
So far the wizards are enjoying the integration of their craft into society and how much they are respected and feared.
So it's mostly politics but also reasonable practices.
Though it's a world sized world, funny sentence I know, so other continents might do it differently.

Comment: @Rekesoft,
Come on. Are we gonna trade insults?
But also no.
Living in a 3rd world hellhole you would be surprised to hear that something like 60-80% of healthcare is charity based.
But also the ruling body of wizards is focused on the larger picture.
You have not read a single page of my story and yet you simply judge it absurd?
Heck. Don't certain countries have absolutely free healthcare!
Besides, like I said before, they are other more useful benefits for wizards that way.
Money is barely anything to them.

Answer (score 2):

1. Well, it really depends on the production. Right now you have an incredible demand since according to this everyone wants and uses potions. However, since only wizards can make them, there's an obvious bottleneck in supply. If the wizards don't have a way to easily mass-produce the stuff, having them be affordable and wide-spread is very unrealistic.
2. Yeah they would probably still exist, since you stated that potions are highly specialized, you still need a skilled physician to figure out what the issue is exactly, otherwise you're just treating symptoms. Because potions are specialized, if a new disease or virus or something pops up, there still would be a need for research into it so a proper cure potion can be found. Physician who treat non-curable conditions however, would probably be rare and very expensive.
3. Think of how farmers use things like fertilizers, antibiotics and growth hormones at the moment. Now scale the devices they use back to manually operated things. I imagine a horse or ox-drawn barrel cart full of diluted growth potion with a spout at the back to slowly let the stuff drip onto the field. They could go around with special watering cans or mix it into regular fertilizer.
4. As I said in the answer for 1. supply and demand are massively skewed. So if the wizards don't have a good source of resources for the potions and a way to mass produce the potions themselves, the market would be way smaller than what you're describing.
5. If potions are wide-spread, every single person would want to have access to them. Places with little access to potions would simply not exist or have a potion seller immediately fill the niche. They are just too useful and if they're also cheap and readily available, it would probably be impossible to make a profit on any form of production not enhanced by potions. Imagine trying to survive as a farmer in the current age using only pre-modern tools competing with the global scale modern farmers. Unless you're filling a VERY specific niche (maybe there are people who don't want to eat GMO food), you're not gonna make it.
6. What you have here is a pre-modern civilization with the potential to surpass our modern civilization thanks to the incredible usefulness of the potions. If you figure out supply and demand, there really is no reason why there wouldn't be a massive potion based industrialization phase going on.

Comment: Thanks man. 
This is useful.